# Server.MapPath returning a path with a folder that doesn’t exists

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, server.mappath

I have following code:

```
var dir = @"Content\Posts\" + yr + @"\" + mnth + @"\";
var a = Path.Combine(dir, dy.ToString() + pId.ToString() + ".txt");
//a contains: "Content\\Posts\\2013\\8\\file01.txt"
stts = obj.NotifyMail(title, writeup, "author@gmail.com", a);
```

And than in NotifyMail function I have this:

```
public bool NotifyMail(string subject, string body, string toAdd, string filePath)
    {
        …
string attachments = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath);
//NOW here attachments contains: "G:\\Program Files\\Derby\\Work\\Development\\proj\\proj\\`Post`\\Content\\Posts\\2013\\8\\file01.txt"

            var attchmnts = new LinkedResource(attachments);
            attchmnts.ContentId = "attchmnts";
…
    }
```

Now the problem is in `NotifyMail` when `attachments` is retrieving physical file path through `Server.MapPath` its returning a path with an invalid folder included in it i.e. `Post` this folder doesn't exists anywhere, not even in the hard drive and I have no idea how it is been picked up and returned. But said this due to this problem `LinkedResource(attachments);` is throwing an exception:

```
{"Could not find a part of the path ‘G:\\Program Files\\Derby\\Work\\Development\\proj\\proj\\Post\\Content\\Posts\\2013\\8\\file01.txt"’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe MapPath guarantees that a path exists, it just tacks your virtual path to the context path.

I think your problem is that you're using

```
 HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath
```

try using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath
```

Comment: tried but still that extra unknown folder in the returned path.

Comment: Anything in the web.config or IIS application settings that mentions "Post"?  My guess is it was a typo of Posts perhaps..???  Also, probably make no difference but @"Content\Posts\" + yr + @"\" + mnth + @"\" should use / and not \, since it's a relative URL, not a filepath.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, You just need to add an extra "\\" double backslash before your filepath, like below and the extra "Post" word (which is your class name) will be gone.

```
public bool NotifyMail(string subject, string body, string toAdd, string filePath)
    {
string attachments = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\\" + filePath);

            var attchmnts = new LinkedResource(attachments);
            attchmnts.ContentId = "attchmnts";
    }
```