# The specified package is invalid. The main part is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

Below given is a merge function which is intended to merge all docx files in a folder and produce the merged file.

```
public  void Merge()
{  
    try
    {

        string sid = Request.QueryString["studid"];
        string stud = sid.ToString();

        string ds = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(("~\\StudentBinder") + "\\Temp4\\");
        if (Directory.Exists(ds))
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(ds);
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*" + stud + "*.docx");

              // stud added for differentiating b/w users

            string[] filepaths = new string[Files.Length];
            int index = 0;

            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                filepaths[index] = file.Name;
                index++;
            }


                using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(Server.MapPath(filepaths[0]), true))

                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < filepaths.Length; i++)
                    {
                        MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                        string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + i.ToString();
                        AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
                        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(@filepaths[i], FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
                        }
                        AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                        altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
                        mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>().Last());
                        mainPart.Document.Save();
                        myDoc.Close();
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

but the line

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(Server.MapPath(filepaths[0]), true))
```

raises the error **The specified package is invalid. The main part is missing.**

I dont know  what goes wrong in that statement. any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably do Server.MapPath twice: in the beginning

```
string ds = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(("~\\StudentBinder")+"\\Temp4\\")
```

and  in the line

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(Server.MapPath(filepaths[0]), true))
```

You can rewrite this line as

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepaths[0], true))
```

and you also need to populate filepaths array from file.FullName, not file.Name:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    filepaths[index] = file.FullName;
    index++;
}
```

Comment: if we remove the server.mappath from that place , it raises an exception - Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\11.0\IEP4TEMP-1310-2.docx' is denied.

Comment: try changing HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(("~\\StudentBinder") + "\\Temp4\\" to Server.MapPath("~\\StudentBinder\\Temp4\\") maybe?

Comment: but to solve this issue earlier i had followed what was said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108399/how-to-grant-full-permission-to-a-file-created-by-my-application-for-all-users

Comment: then, if your file C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\11.0\IEP4TEMP-1310-2.docx exists it is only permissions problem

Comment: yeah.tried server.mappath but same result. @Heorhiy Pavlovych

Comment: Just make sure that you don't do Server.MapPath twice, then verify if file really exists and permissions granted

Comment: I have a doubt. first of all how did that path came, I never gave a path to C directory..

Comment: Try HostingEnvironment.MapPath in the beginning?

Comment: also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105250/server-mappath-returning-a-path-with-a-folder-that-doesn-t-exists

Comment: and in that path IEP4TEMP-1310-2.docx doesnt exist there.. wondering from where that path came

Comment: IEP4TEMP-1310-2.docx situates in a folder in D directory which I created.

Comment: I've just noticed another issue:  foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                filepaths[index] = file.Name;
                index++;
            }

Comment: Why file.Name? you should populate file.FullName, see my updated answer

Comment: Is there any other possibility that this error(The specified package is invalid the main part is missing) occur while opening word document? generally what could it be? the issue which was solved yesterday still shows up sometime

Comment: It might be due to non-existing file passed to the Server.MapPath(...) as far as I can see

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if we have just created a docx and the file size becomes zero. This was my case.